# How can i fetch data from my requests table and put it in users table

Tags: php

I'm making a user registration request system.

Can you help me convert the accept.php file to mysqli? Because i'm using mysqli and this one uses pdo.

This is my code for the user request.

```
<?php
         $query = "select * from `requests`;";
         if(count(fetchAll($query))>0){
             foreach(fetchAll($query) as $row){
                 ?>


             <h1 class="jumbotron-heading"><?php echo $row['name'] ?></h1>

               <p>
                 <a href="accept.php?id=<?php echo $row['id'] ?>" class="btn btn-primary my-2">Accept</a>
                 <a href="reject.php?id=<?php echo $row['id'] ?>" class="btn btn-secondary my-2">Reject</a>
               </p>
             <small><i><?php echo $row['DateRegister'] ?></i></small>
     <?php
```

---

my code in accept.php

```
<?php
include "core/init.php";
include "functions.php";

        $id = $_GET['id'];
        if(count(fetchAll($sql)) > 0){
        foreach(fetchAll($sql) as $row){
        $username = $_POST['username'];
        $password = $_POST['password'];
        $unitid = $_POST['unitid'];
        $worknum = $_POST['worknum'];
        $homenum = $_POST['homenum'];
        $userlevel =$_POST['usertype'];
        $empname = $_POST['empname'];
        $position = $_POST['position'];
        $comment = $_POST['comment'];
        $sql = "INSERT INTO users (id,username, password, usertype,DateRegister, name, unit_id, phone_work, phone_home, comment, position,LastUpdated) VALUES (NULL,'$username','$password','$userlevel','$currentdate','$empname','$unit_id','$worknum','$homenum','$comment','$position','$currentdate,$currentTime')";
    }
    $sql .= "DELETE FROM `requests` WHERE `requests`.`id` = '$id';";
    if(performQuery($sql)){
        echo "Account has been accepted.";
    }else{
        echo "Unknown error occured. Please try again.";
    }
}else{
    echo "Error occured.";
}
}
```

---

My functions.php

```
<?php
define('DBINFO','mysql:host=localhost;dbname=arenew');
define('DBUSER','root');
define('DBPASS','');

function performQuery($query){
    $con = new PDO(DBINFO,DBUSER,DBPASS);
    $stmt = $con->prepare($query);
    if($stmt->execute()){
        return true;
    }else{
        return false;
    }
}

function fetchAll($query){
    $con = new PDO(DBINFO, DBUSER, DBPASS);
    $stmt = $con->query($query);
    return $stmt->fetchAll();
}

?>
```

After clicking accept, it says error or undefined index.

Answer (score 0):

You shouldn't define id as NULL in variables for SQL.
It says: "Hey, DataBase, I want id = NULL for this row!". Since id is primary key, SQL shows error.

```
INSERT INTO users (username, password, usertype,DateRegister, name, unit_id, phone_work, phone_home, comment, position,LastUpdated)
VALUES ('$username','$password','$userlevel','$currentdate','$empname','$unit_id','$worknum','$homenum','$comment','$position','$currentdate,$currentTime')
```